# kubectl multiple net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: networking, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I'm new at kubernetes tech and I try to setup an healthy local cluster (on ESXI).

I encounter many errors that I was unable to resolve:

- DashBoard running but can't access through kubectl proxy api
- I was unable to access any svc exposed in NodePort type (tcp connection reset)
- I was unable to retrieve logs from pods
- I was unable to kubeadm upgrade plan

I thing that most of them are due to same miss configuration/error but I was enable to locate what/where is this broken bric.

If I forgot some information tell me, I'll add them to the post.

I running the cluster on vm.
All vm are running centos7
I have already do this on all of them:

```
swapoff -a
systemctl disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
setenforce 0
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
systemctl restart kubelet
```

For Flannel

```
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=1
```

> kubectl version

```
 Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-27T09:22:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
    Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.2", GitCommit:"81753b10df112992bf51bbc2c2f85208aad78335", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-04-27T09:10:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

> kubectl get ep

```
NAME            ENDPOINTS                          AGE
dark-room-dep   172.17.0.10:8085,172.17.0.9:8085   19h
kubernetes      10.66.222.223:6443                 8d
```

> kubectl get svc

```
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
dark-room-dep   NodePort    10.99.12.214   <none>        8085:30991/TCP   19h
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          8d
```

> kubectl cluster-info

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443
Heapster is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
monitoring-grafana is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/proxy
monitoring-influxdb is running at https://10.66.222.223:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb/proxy
```

> kubectl get deployment

```
NAME            DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
dark-room-dep   2         2         2            2           20h
```

> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       dark-room-dep-577bf64bb8-9n5p7                  1/1       Running   0          20h
default       dark-room-dep-577bf64bb8-jmppg                  1/1       Running   0          20h
kube-system   etcd-localhost.localdomain                      1/1       Running   6          8d
kube-system   heapster-69b5d4974d-qvtrj                       1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-localhost.localdomain            1/1       Running   5          8d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-localhost.localdomain   1/1       Running   4          8d
kube-system   kube-dns-86f4d74b45-njzj9                       3/3       Running   0          1d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-h9c2m                           1/1       Running   3          6d
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-tcbd7                           1/1       Running   5          8d
kube-system   kube-proxy-7v6mf                                1/1       Running   3          6d
kube-system   kube-proxy-hwbwl                                1/1       Running   4          8d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-localhost.localdomain            1/1       Running   6          8d
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7d5dcdb6d9-q42q5           1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-system   monitoring-grafana-69df66f668-zf2kc             1/1       Running   0          1d
kube-system   monitoring-influxdb-78d4c6f5b6-nhdbx            1/1       Running   0          1d
```

> route -n

```
Table de routage IP du noyau
Destination     Passerelle      Genmask         Indic Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.66.222.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
10.66.222.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.25.1.0      172.25.1.0      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 flannel.1
```

> kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces

```
NAME                    STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
k8s-01                  Ready     <none>    6d        v1.10.2
localhost.localdomain   Ready     master    8d        v1.10.2
```

Thank you for all help. Have a nice day.

zonko

Comment: You should better specify the output of the action you did every time you said "I wasn't unable"....did you get some errors? Which ones?

Answer (score 0):

I errors that I have resolved:

- I was unable to retrieve logs from pods : node disable firewall
- I was unable to kubeadm upgrade plan : proxy config misbehaving

I errors that I was unable to resolve:

- DashBoard running but can't access through kubectl proxy api : I have work on this and discover that it need heapster and heapster need other component ... I was enable to make it work.
- I was unable to access any svc exposed in NodePort type (tcp connection reset): I have successfully deploy svc on port 80 but it doesn't work on any other port.

Answer (score 0):

To access **DASHBOARD UI** this is what I've done and it works on a kuebernetes cluster with the following specifications :

`OS : CentOS 7`

Kubernetes components version (but worked for me too with v1.10.x):

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2",   GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:17:28Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-07T23:08:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**Steps**

1. Install dahsboard UI

   ```
   kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
   ```
2. Install `kubectl` on your local machine : the method here depends if you're working with Windows, Linux or OS X, but is pretty straightforward
3. Copy the directory `.kube` from your master node to your local machine
4. Create a service account with name `<name>` (you can put whatever you want, but from my experience is better if you use the same account name that you use to log in in your machine, where you import the `.kube` directory) in namespace `kube-system`

   ```
   $ vim my_user.yaml

   apiVersion: v1
   kind: ServiceAccount
   metadata:
   name: <your account user_name>
   namespace: kube-system

   kubectl create -f my_user.yaml
   ```
5. Create the cluster role association

   ```
   $ vim cluster-admin-role-association.yml

   apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: ClusterRoleBinding
   metadata:
   name: <your account user_name>
   roleRef:
   apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
   kind: ClusterRole
   name: cluster-admin
   subjects:
   - kind: ServiceAccount
   name: <your account user_name>
   namespace: kube-system

   kubectl create -f cluster-admin-role-association.yml
   ```
6. Get your token to login

   ```
   $ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep <your account user_name> | awk '{print $1}')`

   `Name:        <your account user_name>-token-xxxxx
   Namespace:    kube-system
   Labels:       <none>
   Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=<your account user_name>
                 kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token
   Data
   ====
   namespace:  11 bytes
   token:
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (your token)
   ```
7. Now you can execute in your local machine `kubectl proxy`, access de DashboardUI on the following URL and login with the token:

   http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

You can change namespaces to affect different user to different projects for example and be able to be more precise with permissions

To access a **SERVICE** usually, at least with my deployment, you need to know in which of your nodes the service is running (you can get it by adding `-o wide` to your `kubectl get resource` query) and you should be able to access it with `http(s)://<node_ip>:<service_port>/<any url complement if there is one>`

There is probably a better way to access the service (dns names), but I'm still learning too, so for the moment that's how I do it

Hope that it helps

Cheers